# Server can't receive e-mail depending on domain used

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix

I have a mail problem that I suspect is really a DNS problem.

My hosting company has apparently given me the subdomain li173-195.members.linode.com. I have another domain, woollymammothlabs.com, that points to the same IP as li173-195.members.linode.com.

When I send mail to jason@li173-195.members.linode.com, I get it. When I said mail to jason@woollymammothlabs.com, I get an undeliverable message.

What am I missing?

(I'm on Ubuntu and I'm using Postfix.)

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: where are you sending email from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably is a DNS problem.

When I search for the MX record for woollymammothlabs.com I get IP-address 66.11.225.78. 
This is not the address of your server at li173-195.members.linode.com, which is 173.230.133.195.
Your mail for *@woollymammothlabs.com is delivered at 66.11.225.78.

Change the MX record for woollymammothlabs.com then your problem will be solved (if your postfix configuration is correct).

Comment: Definitely DNS, your MX is set to m1.dnsix.com.  This is a server farm wich adsresses in the 66.11.255.0/24 address range.  Fix your MX.